# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null" while trying to send an email using netbeans

Tags: java, email, netbeans

**I am trying to make an email client in netbeans to send emails, but i am getting numberformatexception in my code. This is my code (there are three classes):**

**EmailClient.java**

```
package sendemail;

    public class EmailClient extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        SendMail sm=new SendMail();
        Settings set=new Settings();
        public EmailClient() {
            initComponents();
        }


        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        +Generated code                     

        private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
           // TODO add your handling code here:
            sm.setVisible(true);
        }                                        

        private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            // TODO add your handling code here:
        }                                        

        private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            // TODO add your handling code here:
        }                                        

        private void jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            set.setVisible(true);
        }                                          

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            /* Create and display the form */
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new EmailClient().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

        // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
        private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu4;
        private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu5;
        private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar2;
        private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem2;
        private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
        private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
        private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel4;
        private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
        private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
        // End of variables declaration                   
    }
```

**Settings.java**

```
    package sendemail;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;

    public class Settings extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        public String uname;
        public String pass;
        public String smtpserver;
        public String  port;
        /**
         * Creates new form Settings
         */
        public Settings() {
            initComponents();
        }

        public String getUname() {
            return uname;
        }

        public String getPass() {
            return pass;
        }

        public String getSmtpserver() {
            return smtpserver;
        }

        public String getPort() {
            return port;
        }



        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        +Generated Code                   

        private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            // TODO add your handling code here:
           uname=jTextField1.getText().toString();
            pass=jPasswordField1.getPassword().toString();

            smtpserver=jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            port=jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString();

            if(uname.equals("") || pass.equals("") || smtpserver.equals("") || port.equals("") )
        {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"All Fields are mandatory");
        }                                        
        else
            {
                setVisible(false);
            }

        }                                        

        private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
            // TODO add your handling code here:
        }                                          

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            /* Create and display the form */
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new Settings().setVisible(false);
                }
            });
        }

        // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
        private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;
        private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox2;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
        private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
        private javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordField1;
        private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
        // End of variables declaration                   

    }
```

**SendMail.Java**

```
package sendemail;

    import java.util.Properties;
    import javax.mail.Message;
    import javax.mail.Session;
    import javax.mail.Transport;
    import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
    import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.mail.*;
    import javax.mail.MessagingException;


    public class SendMail extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        Settings setfrm=new Settings();
        String subject;
        String from;

        public SendMail() {
            initComponents();
        }


        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        +Generated Code                    

        private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            try
            {
            final String user=setfrm.getUname();
            final String password=setfrm.getPass();
            String portnum=setfrm.getPort();
            String smtpname=setfrm.getSmtpserver();
            String to=jTextField1.getText();
            subject=jTextField2.getText();
            Properties properties=new Properties();
            properties.put("mail.smtp.host",smtpname.toString());
            properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port",portnum.toString());
            properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.port",portnum.toString());
            properties.put("mail.smtp.auth","true");
            Session session=Session.getDefaultInstance(properties,
               new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                   protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(user,password);

               }

               }

               );
            MimeMessage message=new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(jTextField1.getText().toString()));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(jTextArea1.getText());
            Transport.send(message);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"message sent");
            }
            catch(MessagingException mex)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,mex);
            }
        }                                        

        private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            // TODO add your handling code here:
        }                                        

        private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
            // TODO add your handling code here:
        }                                           

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            /* Create and display the form */
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new SendMail().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

        // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
        private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
        private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
        private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
        private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
        private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
        // End of variables declaration                   

    }
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:145)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:297)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.connect(SMTPTransport.java:93)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
        at sendemail.SendMail.jButton1ActionPerformed(SendMail.java:177)
        at sendemail.SendMail.access$100(SendMail.java:25)
        at sendemail.SendMail$2.actionPerformed(SendMail.java:77)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3311)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
    BUILD STOPPED (total time: 1 minute 2 seconds)
```

`I am trying to send Email with SendMail.java while the sender's email and password is entered from Settings.java and the EmailClient.java is just for setting JFrames visibility to true or false on button click`.

Comment: Make sure that `jTextArea1.getText()` do not returns a **null**.

Comment: `message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(jTextField1.getText().toString()));` <-- there should be your problem. Your `jTextField1.getText().toString()` returns a String with the content "null".

Comment: how should I correct it???....I tried 
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(""+jTextField1.getText()));

But that too didn't work........

Comment: You can first check for null. `if (jTextField1.getText() != null && !("null".equals(jTextField.getText().toString())))`

Comment: Still the same error. I made the changes as told by you but still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: “null”`

As far as I can see the only field that could be parsed as a Number (and give you such exception) when you are trying to send an email is the port number. Having said this you  get the port number selected from a combo box in your `Settings` class here:

```
port = jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

And set this port number in your properties within `SendEmail` class here:

```
String portnum = setfrm.getPort();
...
Properties properties = new Properties();
...
properties.put("mail.smtp.port", portnum.toString());
```

In your code you don't add any object to your combo box. At least you don't show that part but you must be doing so somewhere because otherwise you'll get a `NullPointerException` here:

```
port = jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

However `port` could be holding `"null"` string and consequently the following call throws an exception:

```
Integer.parseInt("null"); // called somewhere within com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect() method
```

Comment: port problem solved. I created an object and type casted it to String...But now it is giving AuthenticationFailedException......plz help

Comment: I'd like to help you but you must provide the new exception stack trace. I think in another question because IMO you have solved the problem stated in this one and now you have a completely different problem. Include also which is the email provider (hotmail, gmail, yahoo, ...), port number, etc. All the info that could help to trace the problem must be included. @user3433164

Comment: **Please don't do that!!!** Post it in a different question. Otherwise the original post lose its purpose and won't help to future visitors looking for similar problems. BTW start accepting answers that help you to solve your problems. If it was luis.espinal's accept it; if it was mine accept it; if it wasn't none of those then answer your own question an accept your own answer. [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) @user3433164

Comment: I have reverted your question to version 1 because of the reasons I've just mentioned. @user3433164

Answer (score 1):

I think dic19's response as well as the comments to your question give you a pretty good idea where the problem is. As for me, I would say the following (hopefully  you find it useful):

```
  // line numbers added by me for reference

  1:    MimeMessage message=new MimeMessage(session);
  2:    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));
  3:    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(jTextField1.getText().toString()));
  4:    message.setSubject(subject);
  5:    message.setText(jTextArea1.getText());
  6:   Transport.send(message);
```

The stack trace shows that the exception is thrown within Transport.send. So any of the arguments in lines 3, 4, and 5 are the culprit.

The easiest thing is to temporarily assign the arguments in lines 3, 4 and 5 into local variables:

```
        // validate your arguments first, always

        final String recipient = InternetAddress.parse(jTextField1.getText().toString());

        if( recipient == null || recipient.trim().length() == 0 )
        {
            throw sometypeofruntimeexception...
        }

        final String text = jTextArea1.getText());

        if( text == null )
        {
            throw sometypeofruntimeexception...
        }

        if( session == null ){ throw sometypeofruntimeexception... }
        if( user == null ){ throw sometypeofruntimeexception... }

        // now you are ready to build  your message

        MimeMessage message=new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, recipient);
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(test);
        Transport.send(message);
```

Validate your arguments on a regular basis, and then, when errors occur, you will have a better grasp of where the problem lies.

Comment: +1 Really good explanation, simple and clear :) And nice job diving into stack trace.

Comment: port problem solved. I created an object and type casted it to String...But now it is giving AuthenticationFailedException......plz help